# update table from excel file MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

```
update initl
set initl.High=Exc.High
from INITLIMITS as initl
INNER JOIN  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\nkavroulakis\Downloads\nikos\excel boundaries\server04testbound.xls;',
'SELECT Validator, SensorParam, High, Low FROM [Sheet1$]')as Exc
ON initl.Validator=Exc.Validator and initl.Sensor=Exc.Sensor and initl.Parameter=Exc.Parameter
where initl.Validator='NV200' and initl.Sensor='Stacker Full' and initl.Parameter='Gain1'
```

I am trying to update a database table from an excel file but i am getting an error on `OPENROWSET--> erron in sql syntax.`
Any ideas how to solve this????

Comment: Well, maybe you should stop using MS SQL Server code in MySQL. Two different stories, you know? There's no `OPENROWSET()` in MySQL.

Comment: So is it possible to update a table through sql using a query???

Comment: Is it a one time operation? I would save the excel file as CSV, load it into MySQL and update then.

Comment: you can use excel vba macro , using vb convert excel data into csv data , and use load command to upload the data and after uploading you can also use update query